# Closed: val append attr doesn't work on mobile

Tags: css, forms, select, twitter-bootstrap-3, styles

Update: i have found a code from snippet that similar to my design which is here: https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/NBrr0

It working fine on dekstop, but but it have problem when viewing on mobile i guess is this:

```
 _colors=$('._select_color_drop li');
            for (var i = _colors.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                $(_colors[i]).click(function(){
                    var color_text = $(this).find('span').attr('_text_display');
                    var elemnt = $(this).closest('._select_color_drop').prev();
                    elemnt.find('span.color').remove();
                    $(this).find('span').clone().appendTo(elemnt);
                    var contents = $(elemnt).contents();
                    if (contents.length > 0) {
                        if (contents.get(0).nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE) {
                            $(elemnt).html(color_text).append(contents.slice(1));
                        }
                    }
                    if($('[name=_color]').val() == undefined){
                        elemnt.next().append("<input type='hidden' name='_color' value='"+color_text+"'>");
                    }else{
                        $('[name=_color]').val(color_text);
                    }

                })
            };
```

Any idea to solve this? T_T

I've solve the problem already. Thank you :)

---

Bootstrap form select styling option

I have a question about styling issue on bootstrap 3 form.
Does it have any chances the select option can be style like this?
[Sample design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6a6L.jpg)

```
        <section>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 text-left form-cover">
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="">Your Age</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="">
    <option>-Please select your Age-</option>
    <option>Below 18</option>
    <option>19-30</option>
    <option>30-40</option>
    <option>40 and above</option>
    </select>
    </div>

     <div class="form-group">
     <label for="">Choose Your Color</label> 
     <select class="form-control" id="">
     <option>-Please select colour-</option>
     <option><div style="background: yellow; width: 20px; height: 20px;"></div></option>
     <option><div style="background: black; width: 20px; height: 20px;"></div></option>
     <option><div style="background: white; width: 20px; height: 20px;"></div></option>
     <option><div style="background: purple; width: 20px; height: 20px;"></div></option>
     <option><div style="background: blue; width: 20px; height: 20px;"></div></option>
     <option><div style="background: grey; width: 20px; height: 20px;"></div></option>
     <option><div style="background: green; width: 20px; height: 20px;"></div></option>
     <option><div style="background: pink; width: 20px; height: 20px;"></div></option>           
     </select></div>
     </div>
    </section>
```

i put div inside option but it seem doesn't work. :(

Wondering it is can use dropdown styling, but i worry the backend can't capture the value.

Thank you!

Comment: Please share your code, so that we can help you out.

Comment: Try adding some piece of code that you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two easy ways to do what you want:

1. Try [select2](https://select2.github.io) (version for bs3 also exists) and write your own styles for this. Using select2 you still can get value directly from select.
2. Use hidden select + [bootstrap 3 dropdown component](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#dropdowns) and write a simple jQuery function: every time a user changes the dropdown's value, the hidden select's value changes too.

Comment: I will try use dropdown component :) hopefully backend can capture the data. Thank you so much!

Comment: @CanDiceYap, you're welcome. If you set a correct value for `<select>` when you can send data to backend even using `.serialize()`.